# Want to display <h2> only if the product have an price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Working in Wordpress and with Woocommerce.
What I am trying to figur out is how I can display a h2-tag over the price in the product-page, but only if the product have a price.

The code I got so far:

```
   $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', price, 4);
function price() {
    if($price != false){
            echo '<p><h2>Price</h2></p>';
    }
}
```

but with this code the h2-tag not show on any page, even if the product on the actuall page have a price. 
Any suggestions to why I don't work as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work if someone else need its.

What I did was to put this inside the IF-statement

```
$product->get_price_html()
```

So the complete code would be:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', price, 4);
function price() {
    global $product;
    if($product->get_price_html()){
            echo '<p><h2>Price:</h2></p>';
    }
}
```